# Run a SQL every time that cluster starts

Tags: linux, database, postgresql

I want to run a SQL every time that my Postgresql cluster starts.

What is the best approach? Modify the start script? Or the PostgreSQL contains some functionality to run?

I use PostgreSQL default install on Ubuntu.

The scenario is: I run the `pg_prewarm()` function that do the `warm` table permanently on memory, speeding up the results but, if my DB stops or restart for some reason, I need to run this script manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Postgres 11 or better, `pg_prewarm` has a `pg_prewarm.autoprewarm` feature.

For earlier versions, you could try to re-invent this yourself, but I wouldn't recommend it. Spend the time upgrading rather than working around limitations imposed by not upgrading.

Comment: Amazing. I'm using `v10` but the feature do the worth.